# I am getting below error while Executing TC , If i insert sleep method it works but gives error in case of Explicit wait

Tags: java, selenium

Below is the error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <button class="disable"> is not clickable at point (377,698) because another element <div class="controls"> obscures it
```

Comment: Did you try maximizing the window and check ? also with Actions chains ?

Comment: Window is Maximized but still facing same issue , but not with thread.sleep method

Comment: "element <div class="controls"> obscures it". Can you check what the other element that is hiding the target element?

Answer (score 0):

As per OP comment,

> Window is Maximized but still facing same issue , but not with
> thread.sleep method

Looks like OP is looking for **explicit wait.**

Having said that, `Thread.sleep()` is also an explicit wait, but worst of it's kind.

so what do we have to offer in place of `Thread.sleep()` ?

- A more optimize explicit wait like below, so try changing your project to this.

  ```
  WebElement firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a/h3")));
  ```

Here is the **explanation** :

> Explicit waits are available to Selenium clients for imperative,
> procedural languages. They allow your code to halt program execution,
> or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. The
> condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the
> wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns
> a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting.
>
> Since explicit waits allow you to wait for a condition to occur, they
> make a good fit for synchronising the state between the browser and
> its DOM, and your WebDriver script.

more..

> We pass in the condition as a function reference that the wait will
> run repeatedly until its return value is truthy. A “truthful” return
> value is anything that evaluates to boolean true in the language at
> hand, such as a string, number, a boolean, an object (including a
> WebElement), or a populated (non-empty) sequence or list. That means
> an empty list evaluates to false. When the condition is truthful and
> the blocking wait is aborted, the return value from the condition
> becomes the return value of the wait.

You can refer the official docs [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) for more information.

Comment: Below method is used for wait  ---> public static void clickToElement(WebElement element) {
  try {
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Constants.ELEMENT_WAIT_TIME);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));

Comment: Here wait of 30 secs is used in constant file

Comment: well, you mentioned that with `thread.sleep()` it works, so I am pretty much sure if you use the above mentioned way, it'd work as well, did you try it out ? if yes what happen ? With explicit wait, one would never see this `org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException:`